# JavaFX: классы против fxml

Tags: java, javafx

Если загуглить JavaFX Tutorial, то поисковик выдаст кучу уроков как программировать на JavaFX. Но почти во всех программа пишется за счет классов. Но ведь можно еще использовать fxml, разве это не лучше ? Какие плюсы и минусы у каждого из подходов ?

Comment: Использовать классы или создавать fxml формы с контроллерами для них - это не "лучше или хуже", а "как удобней в текущей ситуации". Нужно быстро скомпоновать прототип интерфейса - берём Scene Builder (Gluon) и накидываем. Нужно быстро сделать базовый функционал без заботы о дизайне GUI  - накидываем классами. Позже всё равно придётся доводить до ума.

Comment: А доводить до ума как ? С помощью fxml или классов ?

Comment: Опять же - как удобнее.

Comment: А как же MVC модель ? Разве для него не нужно использовать fxml ?

Comment: Для него можно и рекомендуется использовать fxml. Но это не значит, что нельзя собрать MVC без fxml-форм и контроллеров под них.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Меньше кода в контроллере - единственный из плюсов.
Например:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="url" layoutX="397.0" layoutY="62.0" onAction="#startCombo" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0">
              <items>
                  <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                      <String fx:value="http://wwww.site.com" />
                      <String fx:value="http://wwww.site.com/" />
                      <String fx:value="http://wwww.site.com" />
                      <String fx:value="http://wwww.site.com" />
                      <String fx:value="http://wwww.site.com" />
                      <String fx:value="http://wwww.site.com" />
                  </FXCollections>
              </items>
          </ComboBox>
```

это все в fxml, собственно разницы фактически нет, пишите как хотите

Comment: Повторю свой коммент выше. Разве написание GUI без fxml не будет затруднять построение MVC модели ?